# Siebel - Change in MVG data in child BC alters MVG data in Parent

Tags: siebel, mvg

I have an MVG applet present in Parent and child BusComp. MVG Data is entered in parent and when a child record is created, the MVG data is populated into the child BC MVG.

This is causing an issue; if a user modifies the MVG data in child BC, the data in parent MVG is also altered. What is the best way to prevent this.

Both MVGs are based on the same BusComp.

Siebel Version : 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through Script we can fetch the MVG record details and create New record setting the values fetched. Disassociate/delete the old reference from Intertable.

This will ensure that the parent BC MVG data is unaltered while only the Child BC MVG is modified

Although this will cause duplication in the master data, it was accepted in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Are the parent and child BCs also on same tables ? It could be that records added from parent are showing up in child. You could add one more column as a 'Type' column, and predefault with different values for parent and child. Then put a bc search spec on the MVG BC/Applet to filter out corresponding records.

Or..if you are using XM tables for the MVGs, you could change the value in Name or Type columns.

Comment: Parent and child BC are based on different table...like in the example of Account-Address & Contact-Address, Account & Contact have different table but the Address table is the same using same intertable. When a change is made in Address Line 1 of Contact (linked to parent Account), the Accounts Address Line 1 is also changed. Masters maintained in Admin-Data

Comment: MVG is based on Customer table with no extra columns to spare for type classification.

Comment: Check the Address MVL on Contact BC. You might be using the Account/Address link there, and the Primary ID Field will be "Primary Account Address Id". So when you pick a new address , it stamps the account address in the source of the link. You will have to choose a different address , one from Contact to address, instead of the Account/Address link.

Answer (score 0):

If your MVG is not based on an XM table, consider the following.

Since some MVGs (like Account Contacts for example) are based on an intersection table between the parent and child records with joins to both the parent and child tables, then it would be expected behaviour that if you change values on the child table, these changes will then be seen from the parent through the MVG.

Comment: yes this is vanilla behavior because we use a (dot)Associate...I would like to know if there is a way to prevent this either through change of table/intertable/BC. User is not concerned in duplicating the master data/corrupting the master data; just that a change in child MVG field should not reflect in parent MVG.